# fengyuanchen Cropper TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, cropper

I'm tring to create upload images by using Fengyuanchen Cropper Library 
But I'm facing as below errors.It simply can not read or find that file but it is existing in console.

```
   // Import image
    var $inputImage = $('#inputImage');

    if (URL) {
        $inputImage.change(function () {

            var files = $inputImage.prop('files');
            var file;

            if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
                return;
            }
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
                file = files[0];
                console.log(file);

                if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
                    if (uploadedImageURL) {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(uploadedImageURL);
                    }
                    uploadedImageURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                    $image.cropper('destroy').attr('src', uploadedImageURL).cropper(options);
                    $inputImage.val('');
                } else {
                    window.alert('Please choose an image file.');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $inputImage.prop('disabled', true).parent().addClass('disabled');
    }
```

Error

```
TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function
```

Console.
[image]

Comment: Which browser/version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 50.0.2.